# C# draggable map resets to default after releasing and moving mouse

Tags: c#, winforms

I have been trying to fix an error for the last week.

I got a panel and inside this panel there is a picturebox (a map).

Whenever you press the mouse button and you move it to somewhere it moves the map, but whenever you release it and press it again and move it, it goes back to the default position of the map (but still dragable).

I need it to be that whenever someone release the button press, and click and move it again it proceed from the position it is currently.

I am sure it has something to with my `MouseMove` event and I have tried a lot of things and couldn't manage to fix it.

Here are my codes for the `MouseUp`, `MouseDown` and `MouseMove` events.

```cs
private bool Dragging;
private Point lastLocation;

private void countryMapImage_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Dragging = false;
    lastLocation = e.Location;
}

private void countryMapImage_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        Dragging = true;
        lastLocation = e.Location;
    }
}

private void countryMapImage_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (Dragging == true)
    {
        int dx = e.X - lastLocation.X;
        int dy = e.Y - lastLocation.Y;
        countryMapImage.Padding = new Padding(Padding.Left + dx, Padding.Top + dy, Padding.Right - dx, Padding.Bottom - dy);
        countryMapImage.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Would appreciate the help!

I have tried changing some values on the mousemove padding event, mousedown and mouseup events and nothing solved it. I have already tried to look for some answers but couldn't find any that solves the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO remember to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and to vote! If an answer solves your problem you could click '✔' to mark it as an acceptable answer. If it provides some value give it an upvote. If it needs clarification add a comment. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).

Answer (score 0):

Try this: When user clicks the Map, capture the location of the cursor (in "screen" coordinates) and also the current location of the Map control. Now, as you move the mouse (and only if LButton is down) calculate a delta of the current cursor position (in "screen" coordinates) relative to the cursor position captured on the `MouseDown` event. Then, set the new position of the Map control to be the sum of its location that you captured on the `MouseDown` event plus the delta.

One key to having this work properly is to take the `e.Location` of the handler events and convert the point to screen coordinates *relative to the sender*.

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    countryMapImage.MouseMove += onMapMouseMove;
    countryMapImage.MouseDown += onMapMouseDown;
}

Point
    // Where's the cursor in relation to screen when mouse button is pressed?
    _mouseDownScreen = new Point(),
    // Where's the 'map' control when mouse button is pressed?
    _controlDownPoint = new Point(),
    // How much has the mouse moved from it's original mouse-down location?
    _mouseDelta = new Point();

private void onMapMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is Control control)
    {                
        _mouseDownScreen = control.PointToScreen(e.Location);
        Text = $"{_mouseDownScreen}";
        _controlDownPoint = countryMapImage.Location;
    }
}

private void onMapMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (MouseButtons.Equals(MouseButtons.Left))
    {
        if (sender is Control control)
        {
            var screen = control.PointToScreen(e.Location);
            _mouseDelta = new Point(screen.X - _mouseDownScreen.X, screen.Y - _mouseDownScreen.Y);
            Text = $"{_mouseDownScreen} {screen} {_mouseDelta}";
            var newControlLocation = new Point(_controlDownPoint.X + _mouseDelta.X, _controlDownPoint.Y + _mouseDelta.Y);
            if(!countryMapImage.Location.Equals(newControlLocation))
            {
                countryMapImage.Location = newControlLocation;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: drag map]

The `MouseUp` event shouldn't need to be handled in this simple scenario.

Comment: You can [clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/drag-map.git) this example if your code is still giving you trouble.